# Ideal serialization Java library for storing huge repeative data?

Tags: java, serialization, xstream, kryo

One of my class has to serialize huge numbers of instances and using Xstream, the file size becomes like 30MB when it's done. The size isn't really problem as it will be like 100KB when compressed since the data are very repeative. But it takes lots of time to serialize/de-serialize.

I tried using kyro but I didn't really like it. Is there any way to optimize XStream to serialize huge data or is there better library I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd wonder why your class has to store huge numbers of repetitive instances.  If they take time to serialize, they're taking up RAM as well.  I'd use a Set or another data structure to eliminate the repetition in memory.  It'll help your serialization as well.

If that's not possible, I'd say that there's no way to help your serialization issue either.

Comment: +1: I agree that making your in memory representation more compact is likely to be the best thing you can do. I would reconsider using Java Serialization as well.

Comment: I'm making a RPG where every creature has the same attributes are player. I think I have to live with Xstream for now

Comment: I don't see how XStream will make your life better than serialization.  XML tags only make it bigger.